# Does reflow of one DOM tag/element trigger reflow of entire DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

```
    <body>
      <div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div><span>hello world!</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Let's say I change `padding` CSS property of `<div class="wrapper">` element causing a reflow & repaint

***And here's where questions arise:***

*1. Will it trigger reflow & repaint of **entire DOM**(meaning all of it's children & ancestor tags/elements)*

*2. OR will it affect **just children tags/elements**, avoiding ancestors.*

*3. OR will it trigger reflow of **some children & some ancestors***

I couldn't find a clear answer anywhere

Comment: You can check repaint/reflow in Chrome by opening devtools -> Rendering *(three dots -> More tools)*. Enable "Paint Flashing" and "Layout Shift Regions". Good luck testing!

Comment: John, maybe this article will help you understand better: [link](https://medium.com/swlh/what-the-heck-is-repaint-and-reflow-in-the-browser-b2d0fb980c08).

Thanks Reyno, I did not new about that!